# Chmod and relative permissions (in C)

Tags: c, bash, file, chmod

My question is:
I created a file (in C) and then I tried to modify the permissions with `chmod` using octal integers: `00647`.

I don't understand why I would still be allowed to execute this file as I set the permission `6` for the user who created the file (that's me!) knowing that `6` means I am only allowed to read and write on this file, but not execute it.

One of my thoughts was that maybe as I set the permission `7` for every users, I can execute it even if I set the permission `6` for myself which is kind of weird, I think, because that would mean that as long as I set the permission `7` for every users, other permissions do not matter. So I am not sure that is the solution.

Comment: What is it you want to happen?

Comment: This is OS-dependent. In OS X, for example, a file with permissions 00647 cannot be executed by the owner or members of the assigned group. Although as mpasko256 pointed out, it doesn't really matter since this is usually a bad way to manage file access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of file permissions is to provide security.

Imagine that you maintain a system that provides access to a functionality for each user by default. If a user does something nasty you denies access for him. He then creates simply new account to gain acces for the functionality again... Oops your model is wrong!

Better way is to maintain a default deny policy and then grant permissions for particular users to particular resouces.

Answer (score 3):

The OS asks itself - This person wants to access this file for execution.

If this person "anybody" - Bingo - Yes you are so on you go.